# Initializing c++ std::bitset at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr

I'm trying to initialize a `std::bitset<256>` at compile time with some of its indices, lets say 50-75 and 200-225 set to 1.

Based on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset
It looks like my 2 options are:

```
constexpr bitset();
constexpr bitset( unsigned long long val );
```

Could someone shed light on how I would initialize my bitset considering the second constructor wouldn't work for large indices?

Comment: Have a look at [bitset2](https://github.com/ClaasBontus/bitset2).

Answer (score 1):

Bitset constructor `constexpr bitset( unsigned long long val )` is limited in the sense that it cannot pre-set bits from position 64 upwards (as unsigned long long is a 64 bit value). Any bit higher than 64 will be initialized with `0`, as the following example shows (cf. [bitset constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset)):

```
std::bitset<70> bl(ULLONG_MAX); // [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,...,1,1,1] in C++11
```

If you want to initialize also the higher bits in the constructor, I think you won't get around to use an initializer of type `string` or `char*`, i.e. bitset constructors of type (3) or (4).

Of course, for a bitset of length 256, the initializer string gets long:

```
std::bitset<256> myBitset("111100000011111000001110000010101000100000100010010000100000000001111");
// I did not count the digits...
```

Comment: note that [the constructor receiving `const char*` **doesn't have `constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor that takes a string as an argument and initialize it that way.

For example. the following line, will initialize `b` with `0000000101111001`:

```
std::bitset<16> b (std::string("0101111001"));
```

Comment: Of course, that's not a `constexpr` constructor. The OP wants `constexpr` for compile time initialization.