# std::bitset constexpr >64bit value

Tags: c++, bitset

I want to have a bitset constexpr variable in my program. bitset can have unsigned long long value as a constructor which is 64bit value, I need 100 bit value. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753330/initializing-c-stdbitset-at-compile-time) Q&A, we can use constructor that takes a string as an argument and initialize it that way, but it won't be constexpr value.
Is there any possible way?

Comment: Literal strings and the pointers to them are compile-time constants (which is why they can be used as non-type template arguments).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is that relevant to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the constructor `std::bitset<N>(uint64_t)` is the only useful `constexpr` callable constructor here:

```
constexpr bitset(unsigned long long _Val) noexcept : _Array{static_cast<_Ty>(_Need_mask ? _Val & _Mask : _Val)} {}
```

and that will only provide 64 bits of information.

But since it is possible to initalize a `std::bitset` at compile time with another `std::bitset`, in theory you could make a `constexpr` function that initializes a `std::bitset` and returns that, like this:

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr std::bitset<N> make_bitset(const char* x) {
    std::bitset<N> result;

    for (int i = 0; x && x[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        result.set(i, x[i] - '0');
    }

    return result;
}
```

sadly this doesn't compile as `std::bitset<N>::set` is not declared `constexpr`. But looking at the `set` function, in theory this function could be declared `constexpr`:

```
bitset& _Set_unchecked(size_t _Pos, bool _Val) noexcept { // set bit at _Pos to _Val, no checking
    auto& _Selected_word = _Array[_Pos / _Bitsperword];
    const auto _Bit      = _Ty{1} << _Pos % _Bitsperword;
    if (_Val) {
        _Selected_word |= _Bit;
    } else {
        _Selected_word &= ~_Bit;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

but until then, you can't initialize a `std::bitset` with more than 64 bits of information at compile time.

Comment: `std::bitset` really is a disappointment when you look what it could be.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `constexpr` [`std::bitset`'s constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) are limited to

- default one,
- and the one taking `unsigned long long`.

In addition, its mutators ([`set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/set), [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at), ...) are not `constexpr` neither, so you cannot create a `constexpr` *"factory"*.

You have to create your own bitset (or use one from another library).